# Replace every matching string by another one in every line beginning with a pattern

Tags: regex, sed

**Context**

Large ruby project containing code that needs to be updated. Since the number of matching results is important, i'd like to do a massive search and replace with a regex.

**Question**

Given these possible strings hand-picked inside various ruby files:

```
Resque.enqueue Layers::ReprocessLayers, item.id, true
Resque.enqueue_in 1.days, Backoffice::DeleteS3File, "much-bucket", new_file.key
Resque.enqueue OrderManagement::ReprocessOrder, params[:id]
Resque.enqueue OrderManagement::ReprocessItem, order.id, item.id
```

I'd like to replace every matching `.id` with `.id.to_s` for all the strings starting with `Resque`. There are most likely blank spaces before the `Resque` keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this sed command:

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*Resque/s/\.id/&.to_s/g' file
```

**Pattern Breakup:**

```
/^[[:blank:]]*Resque/  # match lines starting with whitespaces and Resque
s/\.id/&.to_s/g        # replace .id with .id_.to_s
```

Comment: Maybe turn on the `-i`.

Comment: what about `Resque ....,bad.idea,false'` should maybe give some security or all `.id` are ok (like OP give as constraint buti'm not sure everything is in this constraint)

Comment: ok `sed -i.bak '/^[[:blank:]]*Resque/s/\.id\>/&.to_s/g' file` can be used for word boundary assertion after `.id`

Comment: @NeronLeVelu: good point, but i don't have to handle such constraints

Comment: @anubhava is it possible to do this in a regex (instead of using `sed`)?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. This is indeed a regex solution but you have to use some tool to run your regex and `sed` is that tool here.